# Is possible wake up tocuch screen on raspberry+iot

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I'm thinking to start in raspberry world, in my case, with Windows IoT.

I want to assemble the raspberry with a touch screen and i doubt about a concrete feature:

When my app need to show an alert, How i can wake-up the screen? (i supose that the screen is in sleep mode by tiemout or similar)

And, when i want to wake up the screen to manage the system, Can i handle the touch events when screen is sleeping? The screen wake-up automatically when i touch it? I don't want use keyboard or any other input method except the touch.

Is this scenario possible?

Thanks